# Restoring system partition in TWRP

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, twrp, restore, stock-rom

I've got an android phone running Android 6.0, with `TWRP`, `Xposed`, `Busybox` & `SuperSU` installed on it *(Not systemlessly though)*. Before I changed anything on the device, I temporarily booted into TWRP and created a `Nandroid backup` of all the partitions.

My device has now received an OTA update to `Nougat 7.0`, so,

Would restoring the system partition in TWRP break anything? 
  *or would it just restore my device to stock Android (allowing the OTA update) with all my data intact?*

Comment: If your device had * any* updates like security updates then your TWRP image will not match with what the update check looks for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restore the /system, boot.img, stock recovery also.  Your data should be fine, but as always, you should back up just in case.  The OTA will check for all three of those things and if they are modified at all (like when rooting), the OTA will fail to flash on your device.

Comment: Lollipop onwards uses [Block based OTA](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/block.html). I am not sure if restoring `/system`(aside of other things) will pass the integrity check. It may be better to flash stock and then proceed to update.